# TFS2017: Use PSRemote from agent or Powershell on Remote Machines task

Tags: powershell, tfs, release-management

In TFS 2017 Update 2 Release Management, what advantages does the "PowerShell on Remote Machines" task provide over PSRemote PowerShell scripts executed from the deployment agent machine?

As part of our release process, we use PowerShell scripts to validate and configure the servers being deployed to (e.g. install SSL certs, .NET version, etc.). We've historically used PowerShell remoting (New-PSSession/Invoke-Command) with CredSSP to execute scripts from the deployment agent to configure the destination machines.

The PowerShell on Remote Machines task appears to involve copying your ps1 to the destination machine and then executing it from that machine's context. Compared to the PSRemote method, it looks like all we gain is simpler syntax. Also, it looks harder to trace and troubleshoot from RM if we copy script files to a collection of servers and then let those boxes execute the scripts while we wait for the result. Given the popularity of websites referencing using this task, I feel I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PowerShell on Target Machines`task makes the deployment more convenient and effective.

This task can run both PowerShell scripts and PowerShell-DSC scripts. It can execute PowerShell scripts on remote machines with a comma-separated list of machine FQDNs or IP addresses, optionally including the port number. Also pass other arguments easily.

Refer [Deploy: PowerShell on Target Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines) to know the details.

And this article for PSRemote : [How to Run PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

You can compare with them.

Comment: Thank you, @Andy-MSFT. I know the task lets you run scripts on remote boxes but we're already able to do that from the agent with PSRemote, including branching out to multiple machines in parallel and using arguments. What I'm not seeing is why (if?) we should switch to using "PS on Target Machines" instead of PSRemote. Under the covers, is the task just using WinRM to Invoke-Command with the script you provide it, anyway? I'm trying to see if this is just a different script management capability or if there is some other technical benefit.

Comment: @pwil301 There are all based on WinRM. Yeah, It's for script management, It provides a better interactive mode, makes the deployment easier to understand, especially for some of the PowerShell beginners. If you are an expert on PowerShell, then PS-remote can almost complete all the deployment.

Comment: Thanks @Andy-MSFT. That's what I needed to know!